# Rationnal points of projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $P_{1}, ..., P_{r}$ be homogeneous polynomials. Let consider $S = Proj(k[x_0, ..., x_{n}/(P_{1}, ..., P_{r}))$ which is a scheme over $k$ (see here for the definition : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proj_construction#Proj_as_a_topological_space).
Let $\mathcal{O}_{S}$ denotes its structural sheaf. For a point $x$, $k(x)$ will denote its residual field.

Is there a "good" way to characterize the rational points over $k$? (i.e. the set of points where the map $k \mapsto k(x)$, induces by the structure of $k$ scheme, is an isomorphism).

Even for $P_1 = ... = P_r = 0$ I don't have any "good" description.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A $k$-point will be an homogeneous prime ideal of the form $\mathfrak{p}=(x_i-a_0x_0,\ldots, x_i-a_nx_n)$ with $a_j\in k,a_i=1$ and $x_i\not \in \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Hello and thanks. Do you have any references of this? Thanks a lot.